# What is the method to show exactly one positive root of a Cubic equation?

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I have $a x^3 + b x^2 + c x + d =0$ and $a>0 , d<0$

$a, b, c, d$ is the function of all parameters.   I'm looking for an analytic solution of this cubic equation. How to prove that is cubic equation has exactly one positive root?

Comment: See [Descartes' rule of sign](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs) for some input.

Comment: Descartes rule of sign is not enough.  Sign of b and c are  decied.

Comment: So the only case you don't know is if $b<0$ and $c>0$. As the answer below details, the statement you want to show is false, though.

Answer (score 11):

The standard method to define
that the cubic polynomial

\begin{align} 
f(x)&=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d
\end{align}

has only one real root
is to check that
its [discriminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant)
$\Delta<0$:

\begin{align} 
\Delta &= 18abcd -4b^3d + b^2c^2 - 4ac^3 - 27a^2d^2
,
\end{align}

Obviously, just the two conditions $a>0$, $d<0$
is not enough to define even if there is only one real root.

Answer (score 7):

$(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)=x^3-6x^2+11x-6$ has $a>0,d<0$ but it has three positive roots.

Added: to get exactly *two* positive roots, use $(x-1)^2(x-2)=x^3-4x^2+5x-2.$

Comment: To the addition: Of course that gives _two_ positive roots only because we do not count with the multiplicity of each root. Otherwise it is _three_ roots $1$, $1$, and $2$. If we count with multiplicity, then $a>0,\quad d<0$ implies that the number of positive roots is odd.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen I guess the Decartes sign rule only says "number of roots counting multiplicity" is the number of sign changes, minus an even.

Answer (score 5):

Let us denote the polynomial by $P(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$. Then as $a>0$, so $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}P(x)=+\infty$. Also $P(0)=d<0$. As any polynomial is a continuous function, its graph must intersect the $x-$axis at  some finite point greater than zero (this is called the intermediate value property of continuous functions which says that, if $f$ is continuous over an interval $[a,b]$, then $f$ takes all values between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$). So the equation has ***at least one positive solution***. But there is no way to deduce from what is given, that it has exactly one solution.

Comment: A sufficient (but not necessary) condition that $P(x)$ has only one positive root is that $P(x)$ is a monotonic function on $[0, \infty)$.  This is equivalent to saying that $P'(x) > 0$.  If I've done my math correctly, this occurs when $b^2 < 3ac$ or $b > 0, c > 0$.

Answer (score 0):

The question can be answered by drawing lots of diagrams of bendy, and not-so-bendy, cubic graphs and classifying them according to the signs ($0$, $+$, or $-$) of $P(0)$, $\alpha_i\;(i=1,2)$, and $P(\alpha_i)$, where the $\alpha_i$ are the real roots of the quadratic equation $P(x)=0$. Here the given condition $a>0$ is assumed throughout.

If $P(0)=0$, then $d=0$, and the analysis reduces to that of the simpler case of the quadratic equation $P'(x)=0$.

If $P(0)>0$, namely if $d>0$, then there is just one (repeated) positive root of $P(x)=0$ only in the special case when $P(\alpha_i)=0$ with $\alpha_i>0$ for some $i$.

If $P(0)<0$ (i.e. $d<0$), then there is just one root if either $P'(x)=0$ has no real roots, or if $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ are of different sign, or if they are both positive with $P(\alpha_1)$ and $P(\alpha_2)$ of the same sign.